# WooCommerce - new order meta after checkout from external application

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, woocommerce, checkout

The issue seems complex to me and I have only some ideas, but I am not experienced enough to develop them on my own. I would love some guidance on this.

So, I want to insert additional order metadata into an existing order. Let's say the process looks like that:

Checkout with all the needed info -> External app opens -> User inputs data and clicks save -> External app adds the input to the database for the current order

I have already studied wp_postmeta table. I have general idea on how to get data from input forms into the database. Small example from HTML form:

```
<input type="text" name="cprawy" id="cprawy" value="-1" maxlength="5">
<input type="text" name="clewy" id="clewy" value="1" maxlength="5">
```

Then there is process.php file, in which the data is inserted. Of course I have connected the database, skipped that part of the code. And here it all goes into uncharted territory for me.

```
$clewy = $_POST ['clewy'];
$cprawy = $_POST ['cprawy'];
$query  = "INSERT INTO wp_postmeta (meta_key, meta_value) 
        VALUES ('".$_POST["billing_clewy"]."','".$_POST["billing_cprawy"]."')";
```

I am almost certain that the above code is wrong on some levels.

Also, I somehow need to fetch the order ID and connect above items with it, so it displays correctly on the order fields in WooCommerce.

Is there anyone here that could help me with this?

Thanks in advance,
Tomasz

Comment: Is the **external app**, a necessary step. As you could always add additional fields to the checkout page directly and save it to order meta. Please update that info, if that is the case I would answer accordingly. ?

Comment: Hey Maharshi. Unfortunately the app was developed by the company and it is an absolute requirement to use it. It is about choosing glasses lens thickness and it has js code that changes the image when You select different options. I tried to talk them out of it but did not succeed. There are two options to do this - 1. Inject data from app to database after placing order or 2. Make changing values in the checkout fields affect the image generated in the app. As far as I know the first one is easier, but I can be wrong. Can provide the link and source code if You like.

Comment: "I am almost certain that the above code is wrong on some levels." - very true. First you should not hard code 'wp_postmeta' as the actual name of the postmeta table is dependent on how the installation is configured - use $wpdb->postmeta. Second the postmeta table requires a 'post_id'. Third you should use the WordPress provided function update_post_meta() which prevents the first two errors. And the reason I know this is I made these exact mistakes in the beginning.

Comment: THanks Magenta, great feedback! Althoguh I am wondering, may I use update_post_meta() in an external app? It's quite JS heavy, I'm not sure I can integrate it into functions.php or anything else inside WordPress.

Comment: An external app should use the WordPress REST API - http://v2.wp-api.org/. This is preferable to executing SQL statements as the REST API also does some validity checking. Incidentally, there is one more thing wrong with your insert sql query - it isn't safe from SQL injection attacks.